# iOS - How combine booleans

Tags: ios, enums, boolean

I have three booleans that user changes values when choosing an option.
To take into account the combination of options I am thinking to combine them using the binary representation.

For example: opt1 = TRUE  and opt3 =TRUE   -> combination = 101 (5) and so on.

I suppose I need to use NS_OPTIONS

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyOption)
{
    OptNone      = 0,
    OptionOne    = 1 << 0,
    OptionTwo    = 1 << 1,
    OptionThree  = 1 << 2
};
```

But I don't know how combine my boolean state to get MyOption.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine with logical operator |

```
MyOption bothOptions = option1 | optin2
```

To determinate is an option3 in the bothOptions set

```
if((option3 & bothOptions) == option3){}
```

I would advise your to google, how does it works :)

```
#define boolToMask(x,mask)  (x?mask:0)

MyOption optionSeT = boolToMask(opt, OptionOne)|boolToMask(opt2, OptionTwo)|boolToMask(opt3, OptionThree);
```

Comment: Tx to your advice, I got it.

Comment: Hey, made for you little define   #define boolToMask(x,mask)  (x?mask:0)